# Filesystem block size confusion

Tags: filesystems

I know that block size is, generally speaking, the minimal operation unit of a filesystem, but I was confused by fio, the I/O performance benchmark tool, which has a `bs` parameter to set the "block size".

If block size is for a filesystem, why fio can set one for a benchmark? Are they the same "block size"?

If I find the performance is optimal with 1M "fio block size", since fio can do this, can I force all processes operating on this filesystem to use 1M block size to achieve best performance? What about remote filesystems mounted with fuse, can I set the block size at mount-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite many details here, I'll try to summarize the main points here.

The filesystem block size is the minimum allocation unit that can be reserved at one time. So, if a filesystem has a block size of 4096, a file that is one byte in size, still takes 4096 bytes on the hard disk.

This is due to the fact that the filesystem has to know which part of the hard disk belongs to which file. If the block size was smaller, then the allocation table would be larger. If the block size was larger, then even more space would be wasted with small files.

There are also other strategies for allocating space to files, depending on the filesystem used. But this is the basic strategy that is most often used.

However, on the application level, the `bs` parameter is the block size of an individual write/read operation `fio` uses when performing the benchmark. Larger write / read operation sizes can provide better performance, because several filesystem level block writes can be combined.

You cannot force applications to use any specific block size. They write / read exactly the amount of data they want to at any time. The sizes of individual write / read operations vary from a few bytes up to megabytes, all depending on the application.

`fio` is an exception here, because it is a benchmark tool.

Remote filesystems operate on top of the remote server's filesystem, and therefore the actual filesystem on the remote server specifies the block size used on the hard disk.

The protocol used when accessing the remote server's filesystem also has some "block sizes", most often defined by TCP segment size, which is determined from MTU. MTU is most often 1500 bytes in the Internet. In some local environments MTU can be 9000 bytes. This needs support from all parts of the network (switches, routers and NICs) to work properly.